# Sorting in django-smart-selects

Tags: python, django

I have implemented interdependent dropdowns using django-smart-selects. By default the entries in the dropdown are sorted in alphabetical order, which is fine. However, I need to have the entry with the text "other" to show up at the very end of the dropdown.

Is there a simple way of doing this in django-smart-selects?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing something quick in js that does the trick. This code needs to be cleaned up, but it does the trick :)

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#id_subcategory').change(function(e){

              var deletedOtherVal = 0
              var select=document.getElementById('id_subcategory');

              var selectedValue = $('#id_subcategory').find(":selected").text();

              if (selectedValue != "Other"){
                for (i=0;i<select.length;  i++) {
                   if (select.options[i].text == "Other" ) {
                     deletedOtherVal = select.options[i].value  
                     select.remove(i);
                   }
                }

                select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Other', deletedOtherVal);
              }
          });

          // And now fire change event when the DOM is ready
          $('#id_subcategory').trigger('change');
          });
      </script>
```